# ¿Cómo capturar la salida stdout de una llamada a una función?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

Etoy haciendo un script que utiliza a [la librería Twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint) pero me gustaría recuperar su output para salvarlo en una base de datos MongoDB. Por el momento solo puedo obtener las tweets en el compilador:

```
import twint

# Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "burberry"
c.lang = "fr"

# Run
twint.run.Search(c)
```

Me devuelve:

```
1334882732543889411 2020-12-04 16:30:19 +0100 <mugikouji_> めちゃBurberryやん
1334882587999924227 2020-12-04 16:29:44 +0100 <styleslthx> @burberry_lxt im gd wbu? and thanks xxx
1334882448153473025 2020-12-04 16:29:11 +0100 <OrmanTanricasi> @tarcinliciklet Burberry weekend, privacy gold sensation
1334882294109151239 2020-12-04 16:28:34 +0100 <iYaimaiZa> @MimiPPPope1 @mintpope1 @18ppdd_27_12_25 @lshamul @SPopezaap เธอได้ Burberry แล้นนนนะ
...
```

Hasta hoy intenté:

```
import twint
import subprocess
from io import StringIO
import sys

class Capturing(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
        del self._stringio    # free up some memory
        sys.stdout = self._stdout

# Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "burberry"
c.lang = "fr"

with Capturing(twint.run.Search(c)) as output:
    # save the output in MongoDB
    print("test")
```

Pero nunca me devuelve "test", entonces no sé si puedo utlizar el output.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la cuestión por la que preguntas (capturar la salida estándar) es independiente de que uses o no `twint`. Estaría relacionada más bien con cómo usar la clase `Capturing` que incluyes en la pregunta.

### Cómo funciona

Esa clase implementa lo que se llama un *contexto*, permitiendo especificar cierto código que se ejecuta cuando se entra en el contexto, y otro que se ejecuta cuando se sale.

En tu caso, al entrar en el contexto se guarda el valor de `sys.stdout` para restaurarlo más tarde, y se cambia `sys.stdout` por un buffer `StringIO`, que es una clase de la librería estándar que "simula" ser un dispositivo de salida (como si fuera un fichero), pero que va almacenando en RAM los contenidos que se escriben en él. Esto es lo que permite capturar la salida estándar en el objeto `StringIO`.

Al salir del contexto se restaura el valor original de `sys.stdout`, y vemos también la siguiente línea misteriosa:

```
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
```

¿Qué se está haciendo aquí? Se está accediendo al objeto interno `_stringio`, que es el buffer donde se ha ido guardando toda la salida estándar, se le aplica `.splitlines()` para romperlo en líneas (lo que generará una lista), y se pasa esa lista a `self.extend()`.

`self` representa aquí al propio objeto *contexto*, y podemos hacer `.extend()` sobre él porque lo has declarado como una clase derivada de `list`, y por tanto hereda de ésta sus métodos. Es decir, este contexto en particular se comporta como una lista (a la que se han añadido "superpoderes" de contexto al implementarle las funciones `__enter__()` y `__exit__()`.

### Cómo se usa

Un contexto se instancia como parte de un bloque `with`, así:

```
with Capturing() as output:
   # instrucciones
```

Al invocar `Capturing()` se estará invocando al constructor de esa clase, es decir a su `__init__()`. Ya que no has implementado ese método, se usará el que hereda de `list`. En principio no hay por qué pasarle ningún parámetro al instanciar esa clase, pero si le pasas alguno se usará para inicializar la lista que es ese objeto.

A continuación, debido al `with`, se ejecutará el método `__enter__()` de ese objeto, y el valor retornado se asignará en este caso a la variable `output`. Debido a lo que hicimos en `__enter__()` la salida estándar estará redirigida al objeto `output._stringio`.

Cuando el bloque `with` termina, será invocado `output.__exit__()`, lo que restaurará la salida estándar y además guardará en la lista que en realidad es `output` la salida capturada. De modo que si al final miras el valor de `output` verás una lista con toda la salida capturada.

### Demo de uso (independiente de twint)

```
def saluda(nombre=None):
  if nombre is None:
    nombre = "mundo"
  print("Hola", nombre)

with Capturing() as output:
  saluda()
  print("Test")
  saluda("John")
```

Y a la salida la variable `output` contiene:

```
['Hola mundo', 'Test', 'Hola John']
```

### Cuidado!

En tu ejemplo le has pasado `twint.run.Search(c)` como parámetro al constructor de `Capturing()`. Como hemos visto eso inicializaría la lista `output` con los elementos devueltos por esa llamada, pero **no capturaría la salida** de esa llamada ya que cuando se llama al constructor aún no se ejecutó `__enter__()`.

Demo de uso mal:

```
with Capturing(saluda()) as output:
  print("Test")
  saluda("John")
```

Produce el error `NoneType is not iterable`. Esto se debe a que en este ejemplo `saluda()` no retorna nada (retorna `None`), por lo que se está pasando el valor `None` al constructor de la lista. No funciona porque el constructor espera un iterable.

Si modificamos `saluda()` para que retorne una lista vacía, poniendo al final `return []` y volvemos a ejecutar el contraejemplo anterior, ya no hay error pero el resultado tampoco es lo que querías:

```
print(output)
---
['Test', 'Hola John']
```

El "Hola mundo" no ha sido capturado por las razones antes explicadas. El `[]` retornado por la función `saluda()` se ha usado para inicializar la lista con un valor vacío, al que luego se han ido añadiendo el resto de mensajes capturados.

Por tanto tu código estaba mal y debería ser así:

```
with Capturing() as output:
   twint.run.Search(c)
   # save the output in MongoDB
   print("test")

print(output)
```

### Nota final

Fíjate que tal como está programado `output` va a ser una lista (con las líneas capturadas). No sé si es eso lo que necesitas, o si pretendías que simplemente te retornara una cadena con toda la salida.

Si necesitas lo segundo, elimina la línea `del self._stringio` de modo que esa variable seguirá estando accesible fuera del contexto. Y puedes recuperar el texto capturado con `output._stringio.getvalue()`

Comment: Muchas gracias para esta repuesta muy rara ^^

Comment: ;-)⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀